# Combine www and non-www in Kibana

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-5

I setup an ELK stack in AWS Elasticsearch. I'm ingesting Apache logs into ELK, one of the apache fields is the vhost. In the vhost field it will have www.domain.com and domain.com, I'd like to combine those so I can setup accurate searches and visualize data by vhost. Currently it separates www.domain.com and domain.com as separate values.

> 123.456.7.89 - - [13/Feb/2017:18:56:19 +0000] thisdomain.com "GET /about.html HTTP/1.0" 200 1446 "-" "-" Server=aws8 SSL=- 634713 0
>
> 123.456.7.89 - - [13/Feb/2017:18:58:19 +0000] www.thisdomain.com "GET /services.html HTTP/1.0" 200 1446 "-" "-" Server=aws8 SSL=- 634713 0

I entered this data into Elasticsearch setup in AWS which gave me my field definitions. Also works in Cloudwatch.

> [ip, user, username, timestamp, vhost, request, status_code, bytes, referrer, browser, server, ssl, timems, times]

Comment: One of the approaches could be to strip www. from all of the hosts you are receiving. Another approach could be to create a grok pattern with optional www. Starting with and parse the hostname accordingly

Comment: How does your *grok* pattern look like in **logstash** ? and paste a logline from the log if possible?

Comment: Will edit my initial question with a typical log line. Can you give me details on how can get get my current grok pattern? I am pretty new with it....thanks.